# TCP concurrent echo server unable to read string from first client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am implementing a simple TCP process-per-client concurrent echo server. The server is unable to read string from first client. However for further clients, the server echoes back the string correctly. I felt that it might be some issue with reading string; the server-end being unable to detect EOF. I tried using send()/recv() instead of read()/write() with no success. I also tried other functions for reading string from stdin - namely fgets(), scanf() etc.

What is the possible cause for this problem ; i.e. server being unable to read only from first client?

The code for server and client is below -

```
// server.c
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 4096
#define MAXPENDING 256

static void zombieReaper(int sig)
{
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
        continue;
}

static void handleRequest(int cfd)
{
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int numread;
    int size = BUF_SIZE;
    int i;

    printf("\n inside handling request fd : %d ", cfd);
    fflush(stdout);

    while (1) {
        numread = read(cfd, buf, size);
        if (numread > 0) {
            int l = strlen(buf);
            printf("Echo server numread : %d len : %d buf : %s\n", numread, l, buf);
            fflush(stdout);
            buf[l] = '\0';
            write(cfd, buf, size);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int lfd, cfd;
    struct sigaction sa;

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = zombieReaper;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        printf("SIGCHILD signal");
        exit(0);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, clnt_addr;
    lfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (lfd == -1) {
        printf("Socket Failed");
        exit(0);
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if (bind(lfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("bind() failed");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (listen(lfd, MAXPENDING) < 0) {
        printf("listen() failed");
        exit(0);
    }

    socklen_t clen = sizeof(clnt_addr);
    int status = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if (cfd = accept(lfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_addr, &clen) < 0) {
            printf("accept() failed");
        } else {
            printf("Accepted client cfd : %d\n", cfd);
            switch (fork()) {
            case -1:
                close(cfd);
                break;
            case 0:            // Child
                close(lfd);
                handleRequest(cfd);
                exit(1);
            default:           // Parent
                close(cfd);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// client.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int clnt_fd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    //memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    char cmd[BUF_SIZE];
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];

    clnt_fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (clnt_fd == -1) {
        printf("socket() failed");
        exit(0);
    }

    // prepare for connect
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);

    // connect to server
    if (connect(clnt_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
        printf("connect() failed");
        exit(0);
    }

    int size = BUF_SIZE;
    while (1) {
        printf("\n Enter a string (q to Exit) : \n ");
        gets(cmd);
        if (!strcmp(cmd, "q"))
            break;

        int n = write(clnt_fd, cmd, strlen(cmd));
        n = read(clnt_fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        printf("\n Received Results : \n %s\n", buf);
    }
    close(clnt_fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is,

```
if (cfd = accept(lfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_addr, &clen) < 0)
```

Here when you accept you are testing the return value of accept with the relational operator < 0.

After validating this the return value of 0 is stored in the cfd.

Let say the original accept socket id is 4 but the return value is 0

Based on the return value you are doing something in the program.

Try to use the precedence for the condition like,

```
if ((cfd = accept(lfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clnt_addr, &clen)) < 0)
```

Now it print the exact accepted socket id.

Comment: From the existance of this bug one could conculde the OP does not show us the "real" code, as with this bug no client would get an answer.

Comment: I can't understand, what you are asking?

Comment: I did not ask anything. I was just noting, that the bug you are pointing to (which obviously does existing in the code shown) would in fact not allow any client to receive any data.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (numread > 0) {
        int l = strlen(buf);
```

Here you are assuming there is a null in the buffer. Instead you should just be using `numread` below.

```
        printf("Echo server numread : %d len : %d buf : %s\n", numread, l, buf);
```

Here again you are assuming there is a null in the buffer. It should be

```
        printf("Echo server numread : %d buf : %.*s\n", numread, numread, buf);
```

Now:
            buf[l] = '\0';

Here you are putting a null into the place where you already found it, if you found it. Remove.

```
        write(cfd, buf, size);
```

Here you are writing the wrong amount of data back to the sender. It should be `write(cfd, buf, numread).`
        }

And here you are failing to break out of the loop if `numread <= 0`.

```
printf("socket() failed");
printf("connect() failed");
printf("bind() failed");
printf("listen() failed");
printf("accept() failed");
```

In each of these places you are printing a fairly useless error message of your own devising, and ignoring the actual error. Don't do this. Change `printf` to `perror` in each place, or add the result of `strerror()` to the message.

Comment: Thanks for above suggestions. I implemented them in my code. But the earlier problem still persists. The server echoes back the string correctly for all clients except for the first client. Any reason for this problem?

Comment: Oh - misuse of strlen() in network code.  That's new:(